# Recursive call with "counter" in MIPS assembly language

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips

I am trying to troubleshoot/understand possible problems in my MIPS assembly programming assignment. It is fairly basic, we must implement a recursive call that updates a "counter" and exits the loop when the counter reaches 0. My error, according to PCSpim, shows the counter value as NULL when I run the program.

```
.data
string: .asciiz "Recursive call counter "

.text
.globl main


main:       
    subu    $sp, $sp, 32        # create stack frame

    sw  $ra, 28($sp)        # save ($fp, $ra) registers
    sw  $fp, 24($sp)

    addu    $fp, $sp, 28        # set up the new frame pointer

    sw  $s0, 20($sp)        # save other GPR’s

    li  $s1, 10         # load counter to $s1

    li  $v0, 4          # print counter message and counter
    la  $a0, string
    syscall
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, ($s1)
    syscall

    jal recursive_call      # jump to recursive call



    lw  $s0, 20($sp)        # restore registers

    lw  $fp, 24($sp)        # restore SP, FP, $ra for the caller
    lw  $ra, 28($sp)        


    addu    $sp, $sp, 32        # restore the caller's stack pointer

    jr $31              #end program




recursive_call:
    subu    $sp, $sp, 32        # create stack frame

    sw  $ra, 28($sp)        # save ($fp, $ra) registers
    sw  $fp, 24($sp)

    addu    $fp, $sp, 28        # set up the new frame pointer

    sw  $s0, 20($sp)        # save other GPR’s

    sub     $s1, $s1, 1     # subtract one from counter


    li  $v0, 4          #print counter number
    la  $a0, ($s1)
    syscall

    beq     $s0, $zero, SKIP    # if counter = 0, go to skip

    jal     recursive_call      # jump to recursive call


SKIP:   
    lw  $s0, 20($sp)        # restore registers

    lw  $fp, 24($sp)        # restore SP, FP, $ra for the caller
    lw  $ra, 28($sp)        


    addu    $sp, $sp, 32        # restore the caller's stack pointer

    jr $ra
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will continue to troubleshoot and see if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this is supposed to be:

```
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, ($s1)
syscall
```

You probably wanted:

```
li $v0,1  # print_int
mov $a0,$s1
syscall
```

And then there's this:

```
beq     $s0, $zero, SKIP    # if counter = 0, go to skip
```

Your counter is in `$s1` but you're comparing `$s0`.

Comment: The suggestions you made fixed the problem. Thank you very much for your help!